# Over ridding Methods in User control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, overriding

Hi i have a user control that contains a button. I want to Over ride a custom function on click of that button like

```
 Protected Sub btnUploadSpreadSheet_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUploadSpreadSheet.Click
  MyMethod()
End Sub

  Public Overridable Sub MyMethod()
    ' this i want to over ride
    End Sub
```

and in my page where i have added my control when i tried to over ride

```
Protected Overrides Sub MyMethod ()

End Sub
```

It is not finding that sub in the base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the page is not a child of your `UserControl`(your page does not inherit from it) and this is the wrong approach anyway. Look up "Inheritance in Visual Basic": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x4yd9d5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

What you apparently want is to handle a custom UserControl's event in your page:

Your UserControl:

```
Class ExcelSheetUploader
    Inherits UserControl
    Public Event Uploaded(ctrl As ExcelSheetUploader)

    Protected Sub btnUploadSpreadSheet_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUploadSpreadSheet.Click
        RaiseEvent Uploaded(Me)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now you can handle it in your page:

```
Protected Sub ExcelSheetUploader_Uploaded(ctrl As ExcelSheetUploader) Handles ExcelSheetUploader1.Uploaded
    ' Do something .... '
End Sub
```

[MSDN: RaiseEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwd3bwed%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: thankyou it worked, but my point is i want to pass a dataset and get into this method
Protected Sub ExcelSheetUploader_Uploaded(ctrl As ExcelSheetUploader) Handles ExcelSheetUploader1.Uploaded
    ' Do something .... '
End Sub

Comment: Then add a public property to your UserControl of type DataSet. Then you can get/set this property. But mind that it won't survive a postback.

Comment: @Syed: you can pass dataset as i am passing an enum to my event for specific change by the operation type..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this because your page is not extending the user control. Only in such a situation your implementation would be suitable

Comment: Then how can i implement Over ride on button click event ? or any other way to achieve the functionality ?

Comment: You can implement your own event for example

Answer (score 0):

> You can not directly override the methods or properties if some class
>   (e.g. Page) does not inherit You custom Class(Control). If you want to
>   do some functionality on some event on the page or button click then
>   create the public methods on the UserControl that raise some event or
>   execute some code.

**Note** - Must follow the page - life cycle.

Check this little code snippet that may be helpful to understand.

```
Private Class MyControl
    Inherits NavronChartControl.UserControls.MyControlBase

    Protected Overrides Sub OnChartTypeChanged(chartType As UserControls.ChartType)
        MyBase.OnChartTypeChanged(chartType)
    End Sub

///Call this OnChartTypeChanged(...) using some method 
/// Or Create your public methods for your functionality


End Class
```

///Method at Parent Control

```
'OnChartTypeChanged is method that raise the event with argument

Protected Overridable Sub OnChartTypeChanged(chartType As ChartType)
    'ChartTypeChang is an Event
    RaiseEvent ChartTypeChanged(chartType)
End Sub
```

Check the [Programming ASP.NET- Custom and User Controls](http://oreilly.com/catalog/progaspdotnet/chapter/ch14.html) 's **Handling events in VB.NET** section.

MSDN - [Raising an Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkzf914z.aspx) - you can create your own custom event argument that hold some data that you want to pass through event. e.g. `e.X`